# Interactive HTTP server

Tags: http, integration-testing, httpserver

For manually testing an HTTP client in my application, I'd like to use a tool which starts an HTTP server my application can connect to and that lets me respond to request from my application manually. I'm basically looking for a tool with a GUI that lists all incoming requests and allows me to select a status code and type a response message. I've already tested the functionality with unit tests but I also want to verify it manually with no mocking etc.

Sounds simple but I didn't find such a tool. I've found some that can be scripted but no interactive one. Do you know one?

Comment: Wouldn't you save time by automating these tests?  You've mentioned that you've found a scriptable tool already, perhaps that would be a good tool for the job.

Comment: In the response, in need to take the content of the request into account (it's a RESTful interface). Interpreting the request is not worth the effort in my current use case.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be written relatively easily by creating the Swing GUI dialog popup inside the [servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) servicing methods.  Have never seen Tomcat running this way but probably it would. Only, mind the server time out. It may be not long enough for you to make an input and require to be configured, also on the client side. Also, parallel calls will make multiple popups that may be difficult to respond but probably this is a single client app.

As a simplest solution, server GUI can be simply disposed after call and newly created as the next call arrives. This will make eveything indepenent on how servlet container is managing the servlets (does it stays, is it destroyed, maybe class is unloaded, who knows). Advanced solution could include the "server servlet" that would interact through its own JSP page but then it may be complex to update it when the new call arrives (unless maybe refresh periodically).

Comment: Actually, I was looking for an existing solution. Not that I'd mind playing around with this myself... But I thought I'd be re-inventing the wheel.